# Скрипт не видит функцию scroolly

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

В файле `assets/js/parallax-settings.js` использую код:

```
$('.collect-terra .container__header').scroolly([
    {
        from: 'con-top',
        to: 'con-bottom',

        css:{
            'background-color' :'#000'
        }
    }
], $('.collect-terra'));
```

Библиотеку в `assets/js/app.js` подключил, библиотека `jquery.scroolly.js`, но получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scroolly is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:24241)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:14492)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:24259)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at _typeof (app.js:66)
at app.js:69
```

Библиотека на гитхабе https://github.com/chayka/jQuery.Scroolly

Мой проект https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B44Y0w-51_ZFWU43R1ptNU9yaVE

Проект взят из zurb-foundation. Спасибо!

69-90 строки кода:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;

var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.2.1
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * https://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright JS Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2017-03-20T18:59Z
 */
(function (global, factory) {
```

Comment: что на 69 строке в app.js?

Comment: @DogeDev добавил в конце вопроса 69-90 строки кода